# (Generalised) Negative Multinomial Distribution

Tags: probability, distributions, multinomial-distribution, negative-binomial-distribution, stopping-time

Fix some probability vector $( p_1, \ldots, p_N)$, and let $X$ be a categorical random variable with these probabilities, i.e.

$$P ( X = x ) = p_x \quad \text{for } x \in \{ 1, \ldots, N \}.$$

Suppose now that I repeatedly draw such random variables until I have seen ${X = x}$ at least $K_x$ times, for all $x \in [N] = \{ 1, \ldots, N \}$. That is, define

\begin{align}
S_{t, x} &= \sum_{s = 1}^t \mathbf{I} [ X_s = x]
\end{align}

and then define the random variables

\begin{align}
\{ X_t \}_{t \geqslant 1} \sim^{iid} &P \\
T = \min &\left\{ \tau \geqslant K : \forall x \in [ N ], S_{\tau, x} \geqslant K_x \right\}
\end{align}

where $K = \sum_{x \in [N]} K_x$.

**I am interested** in the joint law of $T$ and $(S_{T, 1}, S_{T, 2}, \ldots, S_{T, N})$, i.e. how long it takes for every $x$ to be 'hit' at least $K_x$ times, and how many times each $x$ has been 'hit' once this has occurred. I would also be happy to characterise the law of $(S_{T, 1}, S_{T, 2}, \ldots, S_{T, N})$ given $T$.

If the problem is too difficult as is, I'm prepared to make some additional assumptions, e.g. taking all $K_x$ to be equal (and greater than $0$) would be reasonable to me.

This seemed to me like a relatively natural generalisation of the negative binomial distribution. The `negative multinomial distribution', as presented on [Wikipedia](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Negative_multinomial_distribution), seems to be something different.

I'd appreciate any characterisation of this joint law, if possible; I would also be happy to know if this distribution has a name, or to receive any references pertaining to it.

Comment: This looks like a generalisation of the coupon-collector's problem but I doubt there is a simple closed form.

Comment: @Henry That sounds about right, yeah. Do you think it might be feasible to characterise the law of $\mathbf{S}$ given $T$? (editing question to include this)